# Mongoose aggregate giving no response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to mongoose aggregate for grouping businesses. I have working MongoDB script. I am attaching the NodeJS with Mongoose script as well as the MongoDB code below:

```
 History.aggregate()
        .cursor({ batchSize: 1000 })
        .group({
            _id: "$businessName",
            transactions: {
                $push: "$$ROOT"
            },
            numberOfTransactions: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        })
        .exec(function (err, transactions) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    "message": err.message
                });
            } else if (transactions) {
                // winston.info(transactions);
                res.send(
                    transactions
                );
            }
        });
```

Working MongoDb code:

```
db.getCollection('transactionhistories')
        .aggregate([ 
        {$group:
            {_id:"$businessName", transactions:{$push:"$$ROOT"},numberOfTransactions: { $sum: 1 }},
         },
        {$sort:{businessId:1}}

            ]).toArray()
```

I am not receiving any response when using the first code. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Id `History` the correct name? I would assume `transactionhistories.aggregate()...`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit History is the model name (Mongoose). transactionhistories is the table name  (MongoDb)

Answer (score 0):

The `.cursor({ batchSize: 1000 })` method you are using would make the aggregate call return a cursor so the callback won't even be executed. [Source](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate-cursor).

You should use the cursor to access the result of the aggregation:

```
const cursor = Todo.aggregate()
  .cursor({ batchSize: 1000 })
  .group({
    _id: "$name",
    transactions: {
      $push: "$$ROOT"
    },
    numberOfTransactions: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  })
  .exec();

cursor.eachAsync(function (doc) {
  console.log('doc: ', doc);
});
```

More details on how to use cursors [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querycursor_QueryCursor-addCursorFlag).